# i want to uncheck a checkbox on remove filed using splice

Tags: angular, checkbox, checked, unchecked

this is my html file:
The terms i got from api.
On selection of checkbox , it will show selected value in selectedTermsArray.

```
 <span class="suggestermsSpan" >Suggested terms </span> <br>
    <div *ngFor="let list of TermsArray" >      
       <input name="checkboxName" class="checkmark" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="{{list.Name}}" (change)="$event.target.checked? (isfrmChecked = true) : isfrmChecked = false; onCheckboxSelected($event,isfrmChecked);">
         {{list.Name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

this is also my html file:

the terms that are selected on checkbox selection of above html code.
When I click on remove field value close icon. value is removed from selectedtermsArray.
But, checkbox is not getting unchecked.

```
<div>
   <div *ngFor="let selectedValue of selectedTermsArray ; let i = index" ">     
      
     <span>{{selectedValue}}</span>

                                       
   </div>
</div>
```

this is my ts file..

```
 selectedTermsArray: string[] = [];
 isfrmChecked:any;

 onCheckboxSelected(event: any, isChecked: boolean)
 {
   if (isChecked) {
     this.selectedTermsArray.push(event.target.value);
   }
   else {
     let index = this.selectedTermsArray.indexOf(event.target.value);
     this.selectedTermsArray.splice(index, 1);
   }
 }

 removeField(index) {
         this.selectedTermsArray.splice(index, 1);
 }
```

Comment: The checkbox in "incentiveTermsArray" not getting unchecked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the checkbox status while removing the item from `selectedTermsArray` array.

Update you input checkbox like below. Added an `ngModel` to maintain the status of checkbox and replace `onChange` event with `ngModelChange`.

```
<div *ngFor="let list of TermsArray">
    <input
      name="checkboxName"
      class="checkmark"
      id="checkbox1"
      type="checkbox"
      value="{{list.Name}}"
      [(ngModel)]="list.isChecked"
      (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event,list.Name)"
    />
    {{list.Name}}
</div>
```

Your `onModelChange` function is like below.

```
onModelChange(isChecked, value) {
    if (isChecked) {
      this.selectedTermsArray.push(value);
    } else {
      let index = this.selectedTermsArray.indexOf(value);
      this.selectedTermsArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

And then while removing the item from below, update the main array checkbox status like this.

```
removeField(index, value) {
    this.selectedTermsArray.splice(index, 1);
    this.TermsArray.map((x) => {
      if (x.Name === value) {
        x.isChecked = false;
      }
    });
}
```

Working codesandbox:-

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-relationship-lc7q2?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yes, please check the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-relationship-lc7q2?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) Just put a wrapper around checkbox and use [hidden] attribute with isChecked property.